# Relate tickPositions of both x axis values in highcharts

Tags: angular

I want to realte x-axis bottom and x-axis top tickpoint values. x-axis top tickpoint value will change dyncmically but x-axis bottom tickpoint value is constant.

Comment: How it's relate to

Comment: How to use linkedTo option to relate x axis value. But my both x axis values are different.